# Splash screen image goes out of the box

Tags: react-native, splash-screen, react-native-cli

I have a react native cli project which I have set an image for my splash screen.But when the image is rendered it goes out of the box and the image is not shown completely on the screen. Is there a way to set the image size fitted on the screen?

Here is the splash screen:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

How did you set the image to the splash screen? Did you use the react-native-splash-screen package? If so, you could set this in your layout file;

```
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/logo"
android:src="@drawable/logoname"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not provided the code.

change the scaleType like as

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

hopefully, it will work :)

you can get help from here
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType